# AngularJS Ng-repeat is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a weird issue, I can access all the elements coming from my scope as data model, also I can see the scope elements in the Chrome console, but when I try using the model within a ng-repeat statement it does not work, it just does not loop through the **vm.menu.items**. Below is my simple code:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-controller="app.views.layout.header as vm">

        <p>{{vm.currentMenuName}} {{vm.menu.items[0].displayName}} {{vm.menu.items[1].displayName}}</p>  **<<----- IT works!**

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menu.items">
                <span>Not working! </span>{{menuItem.displayName}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
```

I'm still pretty new to angular, so any help that point me into the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this your whole template or did you omit some stuff? Your `<ul>` might be inside of a child scope.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly omitted a portion of the code, this is how it actually looks.

Comment: I don't think you are declaring your controller right.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is legal, just have never used it...oops.

Comment: This looks like it should work to me. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, The console is not throwing any error at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 'vm.' in your html and everything works as expected

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
   <div ng-controller="app.views.layout.header as vm">

    <p>{{currentMenuName}} {{menu.items[0].displayName}} {{menu.items[1].displayName}}</p>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menu.items">
            <span>Not working! </span>{{menuItem.displayName}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1BtC8p1ViqKXSbCWE3Kj?p=preview

Or you can us 'this' in your controller instead of $scope (see http://plnkr.co/edit/1BtC8p1ViqKXSbCWE3Kj?p=preview