# Angular ng-repeat scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

Nothing in my {{}} are showing in my html file. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have no errors in my console.

"GOT DATA" will print in my console, but not show in my file.

**The is my html code**

```
<div class="announcements" ng-controller="onBusinessAnnouncementCtrl as announcements">
     {{announcements.latest}}
</div>
```

**This is my js code pulling from the server**

```
app.controller('onBusinessAnnouncementCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/latest')
    .success(function(responses) {
      //$scope.latest = responses;
      $scope.latest = "GOT DATA";
      console.log($scope.latest);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please show more of your html code? Show us now ng-repeat works.

Comment: @Martinsos sorry, didn't realize the html was not showing properly. I edited my post.

Comment: Answer from Stefan seems correct to me!

Comment: @Martinsos I just changed my question. Previous one might have been a little confusing.

Comment: just replace announcements.latest with only latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! For reference: 
There is nothing showing in my HTML because there is no value assigned to the controller. To assign "latest" to my controller I have to do this:

```
app.controller('onBusinessAnnouncementCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/latest')
    var this = this;
    .success(function(responses) {
      this.latest = responses;
    });
});

<div class="announcements" ng-controller="onBusinessAnnouncementCtrl as announcements">{{announcements.latest}}</div>
```

Comment: Why do say ***your*** to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the `controller as syntac` you should apply the variables in your controller to `this` instead of `$scope`.

See the same problem in [AngularJS Ng-repeat is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236166/angularjs-ng-repeat-is-not-working-as-expected/29236647#29236647) where a repeater was used

**below the answer on the previous question:**
In your repeater you're looping over `announcements.announcements` in your controller you set `$scope.announcements = response`.

Either you change the repeater in `ng-repeat="eachAnnouncement in announcements"` or change your scope variable to: `$scope.announcements = {announcements : response}`

Comment: I just changed my questions.